# Code for cart items

Tags: cart, qty

I need code to check when a user adds a item in a cart, it is already available in cart or not. if it is already available then i want to update the quantity of the item by 1.

Comment: This is Magento's default behavior when you add a product to cart multiple times. it just increases the qty. Can you please confirm that you are still facing issue? Are you adding a configurable product to cart? Are you using magento 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: the problem is when a user again add the same product in a cart, It is again shown in a drop down list , and its quantity still remains 1.

Comment: I dont understand the proper question, if you have any screenshot to make me understand that will work to make me understand the point.

Comment: I want to use a foreach loop to loop through all products in the cart and if it exists and the user adds it to the cart again, it should increase that item's total by 1 but I am not sure how to implement this. What I want to happen is that if a user clicks "add to cart" on an item it gets added to the cart with quantity of 1. If they click "add to cart" again for the same item, it should change to quantity of 2 for that item.

Comment: I hope u got my question. please help me asap, as it is quite urgent

Comment: This is magento's default functionality. Not sure why its not working at your end.

Comment: Can you please share any staging url thorugh which i can see that?